# Spring bean implementing two interfaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to Springs so please don't mind if my question is dumb

I have a class which implements two interfaces

```
public class AAA implements BBB, CCC {

}

public interface BBB {
  void method BBB_method();
}


public interface CCC {
  void CCC_method();
}
```

I am defining bean object in Context class as follows:

```
public class Context {

   @Bean
   public BBB myObject(){
       return new AAA();
   }

   @Bean
   public CCC myObject(){    //Issue is here
        return new AAA();    //Duplicate API name not allowed
   }
}
```

I have autowired the beans in 2 different class as follows:

```
@Autowired
private BBB myObject;

@Autowired
private CCC myObject;
```

What should be the best way to autowire this and define the bean in the Context class? And does defining 2 bean object in Context.java make sense? How to resolve this situation where I want my bean to be autowired to two different interfaces ( and object name being the same..as in my case its myObject) ? Your response is very much appreciated. Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

One point you have missed is that you don't need the method names same as the reference variable names i.e, you don't need your method name as `myObject`.

Spring container simply tries to find the implementation classes for the dependencies and if they are found, they will be injected on to the `Autowired` fields (reference variable names doesn't matter, just their types i.e., class names matter).

In your `Context` class, you can't define two methods with the same signature, so change them to names like shown below:

```
public class Context {

   @Bean
   public BBB bObject(){
       return new AAA();
   }

   @Bean
   public CCC cObject(){   
        return new AAA(); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring resolves beans by their names, because during runtime it couldn't fetch method return type from you bean declaration.

So the best way to solve your problem - just specify different bean declaration methods names (bbbObject and cccObject for example)

when autowiring if there is ambiguaty and spring couldn't resolve it by default specify bean name using `Qualified` annotation.